# Writing to XML file using WriteFile function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I'm trying to write data to UNICODE XML file using the WinAPI function `WriteFile`. I'm using next code for writing:

```
WriteFile(hFile, t, sizeof(wchar_t) * (wcslen(t)), &wr, NULL);
```

where `t` is `wchar_t` pointer. After writing data I'm opening the XML file in VS and get something like a binary file, look at the snapshot. Is it normal? And how can I view this file in VS like a normal XML file (in nodepade it looked like XML but without formatting). Can I realise it?
[image]

Comment: Likely you should add BOMs and such... But have you considered using [UTF-8 instead](http://utf8everywhere.com/)?

Comment: @ybungalobill Thanks for reply, I need UTF16. In what way can I add BOM?

Comment: Thanks to all I solve it, it's project settings

Comment: Looks okay to me. You're using only ASCII characters in the visible part, so every other byte is 0.

Comment: @ybungalobill: for XML encoded in UTF-16, a BOM is not required.  The XML standard defines an algorithm for detecting an XML document's byte encoding if both a BOM and the `"Encoding"` declaration are missing. See [Appendix F](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-guessing) of the XML spec.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That's true, but VS does not use the extension to detect that it is XML, so practically it cannot use the algorithm described by the XML specification to do this a priori. Likely adding a BOM will cause it to assume that this is a text file.

Comment: @ybungalobill: If VS is detecting XML by looking at the actual file content instead of looking at the file extension, then it should be smart enough to check for all the different ways that XML can be encoded, per the algorithm. If it is not, then that is a shortcoming on Microsoft's part.